# Determining what external resources JavaScript loads on a page with a Java tool

Tags: java, javascript, dom

I'm searching for a way to identify what external resources (if any) the JavaScript in a given page is loading from other URLs so I can create some sort of "dependency graph". I can get the resources the HTML and CSS are loading by parsing them, but I'm not sure about the JavaScript.

Is that possible? Can it be done in Java? (Not JavaScript, a stand-alone Java tool.)

Comment: Where would you be running such a tool? How would the JavaScript get access to the DOMs of the other sites, would you feed them into it? I'm having trouble figuring out what you're actually trying to do. (When you say "Can it be done in Java", did you really mean Java? Not JavaScript?)

Comment: I would like to write a code in Java (yes, Java, not Javascript) that, when given a page url, will write what js the page has and what other urls did the js change.

Comment: To get the js is not a problem - I just go over the source code in HTML. The problem is getting the urls that each js is changing.

Comment: @user: JavaSCript in one page cannot change the content of other URLs. It can (with restrictions) change a loaded page in another window that may have come from another URL. But I'm afraid the question as explained just doesn't make much sense, I think you may be confused about what JavaScript and URLs are.

Comment: Maybe I didnt make my intention clear. Assuming I have the path of a js that runs when the page is loaded - I would like to know basically what you said - what changes does the js do that are related to other urls. For instance- if there is an image from an outer url or it calls another js froma different path.I hope this is clearer.

Comment: @user: You want to know what external resources the JavaScript is loading? (Presumably you want to know about external resources the HTML is loading as well?)

Comment: Exactly! And all the resources that the HTML uses (such as images, scripts, forms etc) I can find by parsing the HTML , except for the resources from the script itself. This is what I am looking for. Any ideas?

Comment: @user: I've updated the question to reflect the discussion above.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could write some code that monitors HTTP communications, and run your html document under it. It should tell you in a log which url's have been requested by the document.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can execute your script via HTMLUnit and override Rhino's external loading functions

Just my 2 cents